# Greatest Product of Five Consecutive Digits

Tags: java, parsing, java.util.scanner

I am trying to parse a 50 character String object to an integer. I have been trying to scan in a data file containing 100 lines (each with a 50 digit number) and compute the sum of the numbers.

Every time I try to parse the String as an integer the call throws a **NumberFormatException**.

Here's what I have so far..

```
{
    long totalSum = 0;
    ArrayList<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();

    // Create a new JFileChooser object.
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(
            "C:\\Users\\Jon\\workspace\\Project Euler\\src");

    // Create an "Open File" Dialog box for
    // the user.
    fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    // Get the file the user selects.
    File inputFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

    try
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (inputFile);

        String nextString = "";

        // If the scanner has another token to scan,
        // continue with the loop.
        while (in.hasNext())
        {
            // The next string is the next number of characters
            // that are not seperated by white space.
            nextString = in.next();

            try {

                ing nextNumber = Integer.parseInt(nextString);
                list.add(nextNumber);

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println ("NumberFormatException: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }

        in.close();
```

I have tried "trimming" the String object before attempting to parse, but there wasn't anything to trim. There isn't any white space in the lines that I am scanning in.

**Here are a few lines of what I am trying to scan in and compute the value of:**

37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629

I've check the API and searched quite thoroughly through the Stack. Anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: I think those numbers are bigger than what will fit into an Integer. Try Long.parseLong(nextString) but i think your number is still too big, meaning you should look into the BigInteger class. you can make an arraylist of BigInteger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your numbers are much too big to fit into an `int`, with a range of `-2147483648` through `2147483647`.  They are also much too big to fit into a `long`, with a range of `-9223372036854775808L` through `9223372036854775807L`.  If it won't fit into the range of the datatype, then a `NumberFormatException` is thrown.

You may want to try parsing the numbers into a `double`:

```
double nextNumber = Double.parseDouble(nextString);
```

but that may lose a bit of precision.  A `Double` has 53 bits of precision, good for about 16 digits.  You'll lose precision with a `double`.

To retain precision, use `BigInteger`:

```
BigInteger nextNumber = new BigInteger(nextString);
```

A [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) is arbitrary precision and will not lose any precision.  You can use basic arithmetic and comparisons directly between `BigIntegers`.

Comment: Perfect! I was neglecting the range I was working with. Thanks for the friendly reminder.